# ThinkServer x3550 M3: AES-NI disabled?

Tags: linux, security

We are running a x3550 M3 with Ubuntu and we wanted to enable AES-NI functionality. 
First, we checked whether it was enabled already by executing:

```
# grep aes /proc/cpuinfo
```

However, no aes flags appeared. Thus, we thought that it could be enabled in BIOS. However, no parameter was listed that would allow us to enable AES-NI. We thus updated the BIOS fimware using BoMC to the latest version. Again, no BIOS entry was listed regarding AES, also /proc/cpuinfo showed the same results.

How is it possible to enable AES-NI on this server?

Comment: Which CPU is in there?

Comment: Intel Xeon X5650

Comment: Try removing the stray `.` from the command!

Comment: Of course I didnt enter the dot as part of the command. It was just a typo..

Comment: Check for BIOS options related to CPUID or limiting the CPU revision.

Comment: There are none, except for an option that displays the UUID.